# Angular, how to conditionally style a required field?

Tags: angularjs

I do not want to display validation of my form until the submit button is pressed. When the button is pressed the form should be submitted if valid, and if not submitted invalid fields should become highlighted in red.

For legacy reasons, I am importing a css file which defines `input:invalid` with a red background, as a result any input field marked as `required` will always display as red.

I attempt to make this work in the below fiddle by conditionally setting `ng-required`. Which somewhat works, with the exception that the first time the submit button is clicked the form $valid evaluates to `true`.

How can I conditionally set `ng-required` such that my field is only styled after the submit button has been clicked, and the form `$valid` consistently evaluates correctly based on the field being empty/non-empty?

https://jsfiddle.net/dk89dhp2/19/

Comment: You don't need to set ng-required equal to showErrors, just make it always required. You're already checking it in the css function. I think that's all you're missing.

Comment: @aw04 is correct, no ng-required is necessary, just required HTML5 property. Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bxanLvmx/4/).

Comment: What browser? If I am following you, this works as you desire in Chrome.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question was a mess and I updated the fiddle a few times. With the current link in chrome, if I submit the empty form `$valid` shows as `true` when I would like it to be `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. The first is simply a typo.

this:

```
ng-required="myForm.showErrors"
```

should be:

```
ng-required="showErrors"
```

to match what's in the model.

Once you fix this, you will notice it almost works except the dialog says the form is valid when it should not. To give the digest cycle a chance to run, you can wrap whatever you need to do in a `$timeout`. (Could also use a proxy function that sets the value of `showErrors` then calls the submit function from a `$timeout`)

```
$scope.myForm.submit = function() {
  $scope.showErrors = true;
  $timeout(function() {
    alert("form validity is: " + $scope.myFormNg.$valid);
  });
};
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk89dhp2/20/)

Comment: thanks, this works for me. is the timeout a good way to deal with this scenario? would it be better/cleaner to avoid `ng-required`, possibly use a directive for custom validation which would set validity based on if the field is empty, and then set the `class` conditionally based on validity and `showErrors`?

Comment: i mean it's kind of a hack but it works fine. if the issue was the class you could do it a better way, sure, but it's the :invalid selector that's the problem. if you have control over that, sure you can do something better (basically you could just do what i and others said before the update)

Comment: in fact your whole thing with the ng-class isn't actually doing anything since you updated the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This works:

https://jsfiddle.net/q6ur26mt/

I just changed the ng-required value to true.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <form name="myFormNg">
    <input type="text" ng-class="myForm.getCssClassForField(myFormNg.id)" ng-required="true"
    name="id" ng-model="myForm.id" /> 

        ID
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="button" ng-click="myForm.submit()">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                    $scope.myForm = {};
          $scope.showErrors = false;

          $scope.myForm.submit = function() {
            $scope.showErrors = true;
            alert("form validity is: " + $scope.myFormNg.$valid);
                    };

          $scope.myForm.getCssClassForField = function(field) {
            return field.$invalid && $scope.showErrors ? 'invalid' : '';
          };
        });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, the scenario in my question was oversimplified. please see the update