# Angular, wait until the digest cycle completes before returning from function?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to highlight a field in red if the user tries to submit the form while the field is empty. So I set a `showErrors` boolean to true on submit, and conditionally require my field based on this value `ng-required='showErrors'`.

I define a `isValid` function which triggers a digest cycle to allow the `showErrors` value to propagate, but the function is not behaving as I would like. With the field empty, the first time the submit button is clicked `isValid` returns true and then `false` on subsequent clicks, but I would like it to always return `false` if the field is empty.

How can I force my `isValid` function to wait for the digest cycle to propagate prior to returning validity?

https://plnkr.co/edit/wH6HfawquHJwR69AUPRI

Comment: Not sure if you really need to have a custom function which will call the digest cycle. Angular takes care of running the digest cycle whever a change in model is detected. From the Docs "https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired"

Comment: after setting `showErrors=true`,  my first call to `$scope.myform.$valid` gives true when my input field is blank (possibly because there is no change to the model?)

Comment: In that case, you can just initialize the "showErrors" value with true on controller load (you have set to false now) and it will work as expected.

Comment: but I don't want to show errors on page load, I don't want the empty field to show as red until the submit button is clicked.

Comment: @ab11 you can change class name in ng-click method then you will be able to control input value after submit to set input red or white

Comment: @hsnbl but what if I have a lot of conditionally required input fields, it would be nice if flipping `showErrors` to true would result in them all  displaying as red when submit is attempting. In a previous question, it was recommended that I use this approach with `ng-required`. I just noticed I have an issue with waiting for the `$digest` to propogate before returning validity.

Comment: Almost the exact same issue came up last week here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854384/angular-how-to-conditionally-style-a-required-field/44854633?noredirect=1#comment76690162_44854633 basically you just need a timeout to let the digest cycle wrap up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular, how to conditionally style a required field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854384/angular-how-to-conditionally-style-a-required-field)

Comment: @MikeFeltman the problem is my `isValid()` function, which is required by my framework, returns `true` on the first call, is it possible to wait for the `timeout` wrapped `$digest` call to finish prior to returning from the `isValid()` function?

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience it would be easier to control the hightlight by using css on the form level.

`ng-required` is reserved for use when we need to set `required` dynamically, for example user can choose to input phone or email, then `required` for email input field is only needed when user select email.

```
<form ng-class='{showErrors: showErrors}'>
  <input required />
</form>

.showErrors .ng-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TlDr;** use `$timeout(function(){...});`

The answer provided by [@Icycool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45025583/6434747) does do the trick in this use case. But the reason i came to this post was the reason of the title of the post: "How to wait till the `$digest` cycle is done?"

I did some searching and found [this post](https://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/) on coding-geek explaining the different elements that come to hand in the `$digest` cycle.

It explains that `$timeout` can be used to wait a cycle, (or more, if you add the timeout parameter) It also says that you can use `$evalAsync` but this does not always do the trick for me.

So here is an example where a scope variable is watched and a input element is triggered. It's kind of abstract and psuedo because I do not have a good use case right now.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.foo', function(newFoo) {
    if (newFoo) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $window.alert('new Foo set!' + newFoo);
        });
    } else {
        $timeout(function() {
            $window.alert('Foo was removed!');
            angular.element('input').focus(); 
        }, 2000); // waits for 2 secs before alert and focus
    }
});
```

I've found [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/glRNZ5Wu8JIAcxcgH9Sx?preview) that uses plain timeout's and `$apply`, but you can fiddle around with it to make it work for your use case, i found it helping to understand cycles: https://plnkr.co/edit/1nzydOS7AVONmXh9?preview